# Select a Row from a RowSet in ZF2

Tags: php, sql, select, zend-framework2, rowset

My table looks something like this

```
    id      uniqueId    userId  album
    1       1           1       Example
    2       2           1       Example
    3       1           2       Example
    4       3           1       Example
    5       2           2       Example
```

I would like to find the Album Title where `userId => 1` and `uniqueId => 3` (Where id => 4, but I won't have access to that, only the other two).
 
To do this I am attempting to `getAlbumsByUserId($userId)` which will return a RowSet object with User 1's Albums. Then I am trying to get the album from the returned rowset with `uniqueId => 3`


Something like the below won't work
`$albumObject   = $albumTable->getAlbumsByUserId(1);`
`$row = $albumObject->select(array('uniqueAlbumID' => 3))->current();`

This is the function which gets Albums by UserId as a RowSet

```
public function getAlbumsByUserId($userId)
    {
        $userId     = (int) $userId;
        $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array('user_id' => $userId));

        return $rowset;
    }
```

I could do a foreach on the RowSet object, to find the uniqueId with an if statement, but I have to think there is a better way.

Edit:

I still haven't found a way to do a select from resultSet, but you can do 2 where conditions in the select array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe i don't understand what do you want exactly but how about making your query statement with join you have nice set of functions to accomplish that in Zend.

In your AlbumTable.php:

```
public function getAlbum($userId, $uniqueAlbumId){
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select()->where(array('userId = 1', 'uniqueId = 3'));
    $row = $resultSet->current();
    if(!$row){
         throw new Exception('No row found');
   }
    return $row;
}
```

Comment: It looks like this might be what I'm looking for; join inner. I'll give it a try. Thanks :)

Comment: After looking at join, it appears I can only use join to join two tables, rather than two rowsets, I have updated the question with a format of my table and what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Maybe try to use Where with And if you have both numbers. SELECT album FROM youtable WHERE userId = '1' AND uniqueId = '3'.

Comment: I tried something like this, but it doesn't work :(. `$rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array('userId' => $userId, 'uniqueId' => $uniqueId));` where the array is the _where_ statement

Comment: try to use both methods tableGateway->select()->where() like i wrote in answer above. It works in my projects.

Answer (score 0):

First, I believe that the rowset returned is an iterator that you can use a foreach on and iterate through each of the rows. However, if you want to return an album of a certain ID value, then you would need to add a function something like:

```
public function getAlbumById($id)
{
  $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array('id' => $id));
  $row = $rowset->current();
  return $row;
}
```

You can check out ZF's site about tablegateway here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.table-gateway.html

and information about RowSet is here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.rowset.html

Comment: The problem is that I can't search by `uniqueId` because it is unique for the user. So, I need to first get the albums for the user by their `userId` then I need to _select()_ from that by the `uniqueId`.